# Adding data to RecyclerView that's in a fragment during runtime where data is being created in seperate fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created an app with 3 different fragments. One fragment has a button that adds data to a recyclerview in a seperate fragment, however it doesn't  function properly. I have tried using FragmentManager which causes a null pointer exception, I have tried notifyDataChanged in both my adapter and data classes which don't update the data in the fragment, and I've tried resetting the viewholder which also causes a null pointer exception. I'm running out of ideas.

**My Adapter is here:**

```
package com.example.dogwalk;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DogInfoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DogInfoAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private static final String TAG = "DogInfoAdapter";

    private ArrayList<String> mDogType;
    private ArrayList<String> mImages;
    private ArrayList<String> mDogInfo;
    private Context mContext;

    public DogInfoAdapter(ArrayList<String> mDogType, ArrayList<String> mImages,
                          ArrayList<String> mDogInfo, Context mContext)
    {
        this.mDogType = mDogType;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.mDogInfo = mDogInfo;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem_doginfo, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.dogType.setText(mDogType.get(position));

        holder.dogInfo.setText(mDogInfo.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDogType.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView dogType;
        TextView dogInfo;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            dogType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dogType);
            dogInfo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dogInfo);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);

        }
    }

}
```

**And my data class**

Note, my "AddData" method at the bottom is just to test different solutions, the plan is to dynamically add data in a seperate fragment.

```
package com.example.dogwalk;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DogInfo extends Fragment 
{
    private static final String TAG = "DogInfo";
    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private  ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mDogInfo = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private View mView;

    public static DogInfo newInstance() {
        DogInfo fragment = new DogInfo();
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        initImageBitmaps();
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doginfo_layout, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = mView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
        mAdapter = new DogInfoAdapter(mNames, mImageUrls, mDogInfo, mView.getContext());
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return mView;
    }

    private void initImageBitmaps()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "initImageBitmaps: Preparing Bitmaps.");

        mImageUrls.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Smooth_Dachshund_red_and_tan_portrait.jpg");
        mNames.add("Dachshund");
        mDogInfo.add("You should be giving your dog a 45-60 minute walk a day (maybe split in two lots). Once adult, your Dachshund will take any amount of exercise you care to give. ");


        mImageUrls.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg");
        mNames.add("Labrador");
        mDogInfo.add("A normal, healthy adult Labrador Retriever will need 1 hour of exercise every day. The more relaxed Labs just 45 minutes per day, the more energetic 1.5 hours+.");

        mImageUrls.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/West_Highland_White_Terrier_Krakow.jpg");
        mNames.add("West Highland Terrier");
        mDogInfo.add("The length of the walk is only limited by your time and energy as a West Highland Terrier can go all day long. Ideally, the minimum should be 30 to 60 minutes daily. This can be just once a day, but ideally split over two walks a day");

        mImageUrls.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Buster_the_red_grizzle_border_terrier_%282006%29.jpg");
        mNames.add("Border Terrier");
        mDogInfo.add("The length of the walk is only limited by your time and energy as a Border Terrier can go all day long. Ideally, the minimum should be 45 to 60 minutes daily. This can be just once a day, but two walks a day would be better.");


        mImageUrls.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6d/Alaskan_malamut_465.jpg");
        mNames.add("Alaskan Malamut");
        mDogInfo.add("A couple of daily walks (one is at least 45 minutes) or a shorter walk and a vigorous play session (30 minutes or more). Malamutes can be stubborn, but they are also eager to please. Training early on will make play and exercise and life in general easier.");


        mImageUrls.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Border_Collie_rojo_mirlo_tricolor_%28Birdy_de_los_Baganicos%29.jpg");
        mNames.add("Border Collie");
        mDogInfo.add("Although as much as they possibly can should be the right answer, but at least 20-30 minutes of running everyday is ideal. However, undoubtedly your Border Collie would definitely prefer a lot more.");


//        mImageUrls.add("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Springer_Spaniel#/media/File:%C3%89pagneul_Anglais.jpg");
//        mNames.add("Springer Spaniel");

        mImageUrls.add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Beagle_Upsy.jpg");
        mNames.add("Beagle");
        mDogInfo.add("You should walk your Beagle for a minimum of 20 minutes, ideally 30, and some Beagles may need up to 40 minutes.");

//
//        mImageUrls.add("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiba_Inu#/media/File:Shiba_inu_taiki.jpg");
//        mNames.add("Shiba Inu");
//
//        mImageUrls.add("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samoyed_dog#/media/File:Samojed00.jpg");
//        mNames.add("Samoyed");
    }

    public void AddData()
    {

        mNames.add("Test");
        mImageUrls.add("Test");
        mDogInfo.add("Test");
        FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment newFragment = this;
        this.onDestroy();
        ft.remove(this);
        ft.replace(getView().getId(),newFragment);
        //container is the ViewGroup of current fragment
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've an activity that hosts two fragments:

- FragmentB which holds a recyclerView
- FragmentA which adds items dynamically to the recyclerView of FragmentB

So, the required is that FragmentA has a reference to FragmentB in order to modify it. (Please correct me if I am wrong)

There are several approaches for achieving this:

One approach is to let fragments talk to each other via their activity as follows:

1. The Activity wants to listen to FragmentA whenever it wants to modify items in the recyclerView; this can be done by creating interface @ FragmentA which is implemented by the activity
2. When the activity is triggered by FragmentA, it has to send the request to a
   FragmentB's public method in order to modify the recyclerView

For code snippet, you may refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878496/how-to-refresh-the-data-after-click-the-item-on-listview-for-fragment/54934358#54934358); the difference is that FragmentA changes the contents of a TextView instead of a RecyclerView ... if you need another snippet for RecyclerView, please let me know.